# Java code for Accesing Value from Active Diectory LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am writing a java class inside which I have two methods. One is for connecting to LDAP. The other is passing parameter and bringing the desired values.

For the connection method I want to return 1 if connection is successful and return 0 if connection failed.

here is my code:

```
public static boolean connection(String Prvd_url)
              {  
                 env = new Hashtable();
                 env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,     "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                 env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,Prvd_url);                   
                 env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
                 env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, new String("" + "\\" + ""));
                 env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "");
                 env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");

                 try {
                       ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
                       return true;
                     }catch(NamingException ex)
                           {
                            System.out.println("Error:" + ex.toString());
                            return false;
                           }
               }
```

At NamingException it is giving error `symbol not found`

I have following imports in program:

```
import javax.naming.Context; 
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add:

```
import javax.naming.NamingException;
```

if you are using eclipse simply press ctrl+shift+o